# Mobile Hybrid App testing

Tags: android, testing

I am looking for testing tools for Mobile Hybrid Application. I tried Monkey Talk best 5 but it does not fully support javascript testing.

Please suggest another platforms/tools available in market

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Sikuli - > http://sikuli.org/

Comment: Sikuli works well with emulator. Can you suggest some tool that works with Device as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try http://testobject.com, think of it as a Sikuli for Mobile

Answer (score 1):

Currently I am using FoneMonkey, UTF/QTP for iOS and Robotium for Android and find these are best tools for mobile application testing.

Answer (score 0):

SeeTest provides full support on hybrid applications. 
See here (under web identification) http://experitest.com/support/features-2/